# Cancelling notification from BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I use `BroadcastReceiver` to process some data after user clicks on action button from notification.

So in order to achieve that first I build PendingIntent:

```
val intent = Intent(context, CustomBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
    action = MY_ACTION
    // Also put some extras here like notification id.
}

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
```

And this is called from `Service` which builds and shows the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.text))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .addAction(actionIcon, actionTitle, pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()
```

Then in CustomBroadcastReceiver I'm cancelling this notification (I have notification ID from intent):

```
getNotificationManager().cancel(notificationId)
```

The problem is that notification is not dismissed, it's till on notification drawer.

I saw answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062798/notificationmanager-cancelid-is-not-working-inside-a-broadcast-receiver), but it doesn't help - I'm using `applicationContext`, notificationId is correct and it's greater than 0.

Comment: How are you getting Notification manager in getNotificationManager().cancel(notificationId) ?

Comment: Just a thought, since you’re using NotificationCompat.Builder, have you also tried using NotificationManagerCompat do handle the cancel?